# ¿como ejecutar un array de funciones en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validación

Hola que tal amigos tengo una duda poraqui con el tema de jquery basicamente tengo un array de funciones asi

```
valFuncs={'noempty':function(item){

        },
        'max-lenght':function(item){

        },
        'min-lenght':function(item){

        },
        'alfa':function(item){

        },
       'email':function(item){

        }

     }
```

No se si es posible ejecutar estas funciones.
Lo que quiero hacer es definir otro arreglo con el input de llave y que contenga un arreglo con las funciones que necesita para validarse.
Algo asi

```
inputsVal={'username':{'noempty':true,'max-lenght':30,'min-lenght':4,'alfa':true},
         'password':{'noempty':true,'min-lenght':6},
        }
```

recorrer este ultimo array en un each y ejecutar las funciones para validarlo.
Actualmente tengo mi codigo asi.

```
  $("#regForm").on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
inputs= $(this).find('input');

inputs.each(function(i){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));

  actual = inputsVal[$(this).attr('id')];
  $.each(actual,function(key,value){
    funcion = key;


  });


});
```

})

Alguien me podria decir si se puede?
y si se puede como llamo a la funciion pasandole el argumento.

les agradeceria que me ayudaran con esto gracias.
Aclaro que no se si se peude solo se me ocurrio asi y quiero averiguar si se puede. Busque en internet pero no encuentro algo parecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que tengas este objeto con las funciones de validación, debo señalar que las funciones retornan true si no se cumple la validación y basado en esto tenemos lo siguiente:

```
valFuncs={
 //Que no este vacio
'noempty':function(item){
  return item && item.toString().length === 0;
},

//Que tenga un maximo largo la cadena
'max-lenght':function(item, max){
  return item && item.toString().length > max;
},

//Que tenga un minimo de largo la cadena
'min-lenght':function(item, min){
  return item && item.toString().length < min;
},

//Que sea alfanumerico el valor
'alfa':function(item){
   return item && /^\W+$/.test(item)
},

//El del email es parecido al anterior
}

var inputsVal = {
 'username':{'noempty':true,'max-lenght':30,'min-lenght':4,'alfa':true},
 'password':{'noempty':true,'min-lenght':6},
}

$("#regForm").on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //Obtienes todos los campos, debes obtener solo los visibles, por si en un futuro
  //quieres usar tabs y validar solo la página activa
  var inputs= $(this).find('input:visible');

  //Recorres todos los campos encontrados para validarlos
  inputs.each(function(i){
  //Obtienes el id del campo actual de la iteración
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  //Obtienes el valor del campo actual de la iteración
  var value = $(this).val();
  //Obtienes la validación que vas a aplicar
  var actual = inputsVal[id];
  $.each(actual,function(key,val){
    functionName = key;
    //Nombres de funciones que no reciben parámetros
    var noParameters = ['noempty', 'alpha'];
    //Si no lleva parametro la llamo solo pasandole el valor del campo
    //Sino le paso el valor mas el parametro
    var funcion = noParameters.includes(key) 
      ? valFuncs[functionName](value)
      : valFuncs[functionName](value, val);
    //Si funcion es true quiere decir que la validación falló, entonces..
    if(funcion) {
      alert('El campo con id: ' + id + ' tiene datos incorrectos');
    }  
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: Dime que tal te va para ayudarte a mejorarlo un poco más. Saludos

Comment: #Dariel Hola amigo agradesco que repondieras pero no consigo que se ejecute la funcion osea en todos los casos me retorna falso el if  a vos te funciono ? si a vos te funciono debo tener algun error enel codigo

Comment: Okey lo consegui solo tenia que modificar las condiciones de los returs pero si funciono gracias amigo ^^